# trivial theorem about my inductive type on Coq

Tags: coq

I defined the dependent type and trivial lemma as you can see below.

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Inductive Euc :nat -> Type:=
|RO : Euc 0
|Rn : forall {n:nat}, R -> Euc n -> Euc (S n).

Lemma ROEuc : forall t:(Euc 0), t = RO.
Proof.
intros. Admitted.
```

I don't know how to prove it.
`Euc 0` is not an inductive type, so I can not use `destruct t` or `induction t`.

Please tell me how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, Coq is actually smart enough to do the dependent pattern matching for you.
The magic tactic to use here is `refine (match t in Euc 0 with RO => _)`, which leaves you with a single trivial goal (there may be a variant of destruct that does this, but I don't know what it would be). Here the clause `in Euc 0` tells Coq that you are only interested in 0-length vectors, and since 0 is a `nat` built from constructors, Coq is able to work out that the `RS` case is impossible by disjointness of constructors.

The full proof:

```
Lemma ROEuc : forall t:(Euc 0), t = RO.
Proof.
intros.
refine (match t in Euc 0 with RO => _ end).
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The proof term generated by this match is actually rather complicated, but understanding it might be helpful if you need to write other proofs about dependent types where Coq's pattern matching isn't powerful enough to help you.

Answer (score 4):

You should find it easy to prove the more simply-typed theorem

```
Lemma ROEuc' : forall n (t : Euc n), n = 0 -> existT Euc n t = existT Euc 0 RO.
```

You can simply `destruct t`, giving you one trivial case, and one absurd case that can be discharged with `congruence`.

To derive your lemma from this one, you will need four tools:

1. The `inversion_sigma` tactic to turn an equality of `existT` s into dependent equalities
2. The fact `UIP_dec` from [`Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html) to prove that all proofs of `0 = 0` are equal to `eq_refl` under the assumption that equality of `nat` is decidable
3. The fact that equality of `nat` is decidable, which you can either take from some lemma in `Coq.Arith.Arith` (use `Search` after  `Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith` to find the name of the lemma with the right type) or prove from scratch using the `decide equality` tactic
4. `subst` + `simpl` to see that your dependent equality will now reduce to the theorem you want to prove

---

Alternatively, you can `Require Import Coq.Program.Tactics` and use `dependent destruction t`, but beware that this often introduces needless dependencies on axioms (visible with `Print Assumptions`)

Comment: Jason, the lemma you wrote is not provable. Did you mean to write `forall (t : Euc 0), ...`?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include `n = 0` as a hypothesis.  Now fixed.  Though the one you wrote works as well.